# Can generalised continued fractions always be written so that they are simple?

Tags: number-theory, fractions, continued-fractions

Can every generalised continued fraction be written in simple continued fraction form? If not, how else does one represent a generalised continued fraction using the standard $[a_0;a_1,a_2,\ldots]$ notation when there are $b_1,b_2,\ldots$ to consider?

Comment: Every real number can be written as s simple continued fraction, so yes , assuming the original generalized continued fraction converges towards a real number. There should even be rules for the conversion.

Answer (score 0):

How does one represent ...
There is [this notation](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/12403/first-use-of-k-in-notation-for-continued-fractions)
$$
a_0 + \underset{k=1}{\overset{\infty}{\sf K}} \frac{b_k}{a_k} = 
a_0 + \cfrac{b_1}{a_1 + \cfrac{b_2}{a_2 + \cfrac{b_3}{a_3 + \cfrac{b_4\;\;}{{\ddots}}}}}.
$$